Splunk DB Connect and Snowflake Integration Error ( Private Key )
By using the self-service app install process on Victoria experience, the Splunk db connect and snowflake driver have been installed.
The connection string is as follow:
jdbc:snowflake://xxxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com?authenticator=snowflake_jwt&user=xxx&role=xxxx&application=SPLUNK&private_key_base64=MIIE…

The provided private key is the PEM File encoded in base64.
The connection work fine locally on a java application using the JDBC Drivers but I do have that error while testing the connection on Splunk;

Private key provided is invalid or not supported: Use java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey.class for the private key

I have searched the community threads for posts similar to this, but none have quite addressed the issue I am seeing.

The issue come from a version mismatch between the latest JDBC Drivers and the one deployed on Splunk where the feature doesn't exist.
